# Hashing function gives different output when running Maven JUnit tests on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testing, hash

As the title says,  have this function which takes as arguments a ByteArrayResource and a String representing the name of the algorithm to use.

I'm using `java.security.MessageDigest` with `GnuCrypto` and `BouncyCastleProvider` providers.

I'm having some issues identifying what the problem could be, both my machine and the Jenkins one are running java 11, here's the code:

Test:

```
void hashOk{
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("path/to/file.xml"));

    String hash1 = "5EDF3285285FDABCFFB7019E2442B31F";
    String hash2 = hashService.hash(new ByteArrayResource(bytes), "MD5");

    Assertions.assertEquals(hash1, hash2);
}
```

Service:

```
public String hash(ByteArrayResource obj, String algorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    Security.addProvider(new GnuCrypto());

    var md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);

    try (DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(obj.getInputStream()), md)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (dis.read(buffer) != -1) ;

        byte[] hash = md.digest();

        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash).toUpperCase();

    } catch (IOException e) {...} }
```

Am I missing something?

These are the results of the test, where "hash1" is the control string and "hash2" is the generated one:

Local MD5

```
hash1: 5EDF3285285FDABCFFB7019E2442B31F
hash2: 5EDF3285285FDABCFFB7019E2442B31F
```

Jenkins MD5

```
hash1: 5EDF3285285FDABCFFB7019E2442B31F 
hash2: 7A7E0BBA2452963746BA4D71EB8CCFA3
```

I've also tried on a different machine with Jenkins and it gives the same results.

Some solutions I found were just a different arrangement of the same code (and I tried them).

There's one which told me to change the `pom.xml` and set the `forkCount` property to 0 on the `maven-surefire-plugin`, but that gave me an exception because it couldn't find the file for the hashing test (?).

Comment: If the hash is different, then the overwhelmingly most likely explanation is that the content that you hash is different. What is `obj.getInputStream()`? Are you sure that it's byte-for-byte the same data every time?

Comment: The code you are showing is deterministic enough. The problem is unlikely to be in this bit. Look elsewhere. Or try to distill it into a [mre].

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes, the file i'm hashing for the test is located inside the test/resources folder of the project

Comment: @GianlucaSacchi: then you do something wrong with reading/converting to bytes. Show us the code to actually read the content (or better yet, reduce it to a [mre] that shows the problem with minimal code, as also suggested by teapot418). I'm almost 100% sure that for some reason `obj.getInputStream()` doesn't return the same stream of bytes on both environments. A common source for this is usage of `String.getBytes()` or other methods that rely on the platform default encoding.

Comment: @JoachimSauer done, so if that's the case it must be a test-related issue, that would be a relief

Comment: Another possibility for different bytes: if you check out source from source control and on a Windows system you have line ending conversion activated (LF to CRLF) and on Jenkins there is no line ending conversion.

Comment: @GianlucaSacchi: the code does not have the encoding problem I alluded to (as you purely handle the data as `byte[]` and never convert to/from `String`), so the thing that Thomas Kläger mentions is the (or a?) likely cause. You probably want to use `.gitattributes` to ensure files are always checked out in the same way accross systems.

Comment: Btw: if the line endings are the issue, then simply printing the *length* or the byte array should show a difference between the two (because using CRLF would add 1 byte to each line compared to just LF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, it really was an issue with the reading of the file.

After I've put the file content in a single line and changed the code to read that file one time only instead of once per test it all worked.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The code you showed for reading is correct and doesn't cause the issue. If putting the file content on a single line solved it, that means that the CRLF difference is indeed the root cause: Git on windows will use CRLF instead of LF for line endings (depending on .gitattributes and local git configuration, but it's the default). You should really look into that (unfortunately a quick search didn't find any good SO answers on that topic, mostly because git changed so much and the advice I find is a mixture of various "generations" of solutions). Mostly just `* text=auto eol=lf` should work.